# Фильтрация WiFi трафика домашней сети

Tags: фильтрация, router, wifi, роутер, трафик

Я не опытен в этом деле, поэтому хотелось бы хотя бы получить общие ответы возможно ли вообще или нет, и если да то возможно какие то советы, как и что :)

Дома стоит роутер, который раздает интернет по WiFi (или по кабелю к нему можно подключится напрямую).  Если имеет значение, то роутер Huawei HG8245H.

Нужно получить возможность как минимум анализировать трафик (какое устройство, сколько трафика потребляет), и по возможности больше, к примеру, откуда и куда и какие запросы иду, фильтрация трафика (закрытие доступа к каким либо адресам), ограничение трафика (ограничение скорости) и так далее.

Собственно вопрос в этом, можно ли получить такие возможности при наличии ноутбука и роутера (естественно доступ к настройке роутера есть), без необходимости докупать что либо ?

В настройках лазил, и ничего похожего не нашел.

Спасибо.

*Упсс, я случайно не там вопрос задал, лучше бы его задать на admin.hashcode.ru  только он не работает видимо, пере-адресация происходит на эту версию :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Упсс, я случайно не там вопрос задал,
> лучше бы его задать на
> admin.hashcode.ru только он не
> работает видимо, пере-адресация
> происходит на эту версию :)

[admin.hashcode.ru объединили с hashcode.ru](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/research/2295)

> Собственно вопрос в этом, можно ли
> получить такие возможности при наличии
> ноутбука и роутера (естественно доступ
> к настройке роутера есть), без
> необходимости докупать что либо?

Нет. У вас специфический роутер для PON сетей, на него даже альтернативных прошивок не сыскать.

> Нужно получить возможность как минимум
> анализировать трафик (какое
> устройство, сколько трафика
> потребляет), и по возможности больше,
> к примеру, откуда и куда и какие
> запросы иду, фильтрация трафика
> (закрытие доступа к каким либо
> адресам), ограничение трафика
> (ограничение скорости) и так далее.

Подобные возможности у домашних роутеров (*на заводских прошивках*) встречаются очень редко, самое большее - это родительский контроль с запретом доступа к определённым сайтам.

В вашем роутере смотрите раздел `Security -> URL Filter`, это фильтрация по списку URL адресов.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Жаль, думал что можно будет установить какую то программу на комп для получения таких возможностей :)